# Different mapping depending on enclosing class

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Say I have a `SourceClass`:

```
public class SourceClass
{
    IList<InnerClass> InnerCollection{get; set;}

    // other properties...
}
```

and two different destination classes:

```
public class DestinationClass1
{
    IList<InnerClassDto> InnerCollection{get; set;}

    // other properties...
}

public class DestinationClass2
{
    IList<InnerClassDto> InnerCollection{get; set;}

    // other properties...
}
```

Finally I configured my mapper:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass1>();
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass2>();
    cfg.CreateMap<InnerClass, InnerClassDto>();
});
```

But I need to populate `IList<InnerClassDto>` in my destination classes depending on "parent" class. In particular I need to filter some elements for `DestinationClass1`, and keep all elements for `DestinationClass2`.

Which is the correct way to achieve this with Automapper? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a filter in mapping configuration :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass1>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.InnerCollection, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.InnerCollection.Where(o => o.Value == src.CustomValue)));
```